# Solidity error when encoding arguments to call a function with Bytes32 Type Parameters

Tags: solidity, remix

While developing a Smart Contract with Solidity on Remix, after creating the contract I'm trying to call a function by passing Bytes32 datatype parameters:

```
function addTT(bytes32 _name) public {
...
}
```

but when I call addTT() by passing parameter "neo" it throws the following error:

> transact to Abc.addTT errored: Error encoding arguments: Error:
>   invalid bytes32 value (arg=undefined, type="string", value="asda")

Any idea how can I properly **call function addTT()**?

Comment: I tried the same way but it is still throwing the error, saying "Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1. I am getting irritated by this, please help me

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30024)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the value in hex to be passed. *neo* is *0x6e656f* in hex. If you try to pass '0x6e656f' it will work (don't forget the quote).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string instead of bytes32 in Remix which has higher gas cost and hence less efficient.